# 2 Unsorted List Files, need the missing links

Tags: search

I have 2 list files, of which one is missing lines.
However, both files are NOT sorted equally, thus, each line has a different place in both.

How do I find and list specifically the missing lines in the copy?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I ask for assistance with an issue, not code related?
I think?